# Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml"

Tags: flutter

hi friends how to solve this error,i'm just running  this command flutter:

- Flutter doctor -v,
  flutter pub cache clean ,
  flutter pub cache repair,
  flutter packages pub get,
  flutter clean,
  dart pub get ,
  flutter pub get,

i'm getting an error
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "E:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\test_api-0.4.8".
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...
pub get failed (66; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in
"E:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\test_api-0.4.8".)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Really frustrating.I deleted the pub.dartlang.org folder.

On Mac, in finder command + shift + G | pasted the path from the console | opened in finder and removed the folder.

after deleting the folder
**run**

- Pub get
- pub outdated / upgrade
- pod repo update
- pod update

This fixed my issue and allowed me to build the app.